# Systems of equations over reals

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve over reals
>   $$2x^2+xy+x-3y+3=0$$
>   $$3xy+y^2-2x+6y-6=0$$

Adding or subtracting these equations doesn't help, and completing the square also doesn't work. I'm considering substituting $x+y$ and $xy$, but it also doesn't show much promise. Thanks!

Comment: Multiplying the first equation by two, then adding the result to the second equation, gives:

$$4x^2+5xy+y^2=0$$

which is equivalent to

$$(2x+y)^2=-xy$$

Since the left hand side is non-negative (it's a square), the right hand side must be non-negative as well $$-xy \geq 0 $$

We can exclude $x=0$ or $y=0$ quite easily, by plugging them in. Therefore, $$-xy > 0$$ is a strict inequality, which means that $x$ and $y$ must be opposite signs.

Comment: On another note, both the first equation and the second equations are equations of [conic sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section). In particular, they are the equations of [hyperbolas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$2x^2+xy+x-3y+3=0\tag{1}$$
$$3xy+y^2-2x+6y-6=0\tag{2}$$

Take 2$\times$(1)+(2) to get,

$$4x^2+5xy+y^2=0 \implies (4x+y)(x+y)=0$$

which yields $y=-x$ and $y=-4x$. Plug them into (1)

$$x^2+4x+3=0\implies x=-1,\>x=-3$$
$$2x^2-13x-3=0\implies x=\frac{13\pm\sqrt{193}}{4}$$

Then, evaluated the corresponding $y$'s to obtain the follow solutions,

$$(-1,1),\>\>\>(-3,3),\>\>\>
\left(\frac{13+\sqrt{193}}{4},-13-\sqrt{193}\right),
\left(\frac{13-\sqrt{193}}{4},-13+\sqrt{193}\right)$$

Comment: Nice, +1 I missed the factorization of $4x^2+5xy+y^2=0$

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee - Just saw your comments. Similar path.

Comment: Yes, always worth a try to get rid of the additive constants.

Answer (score 1):

*Another way to do it.*

From the first equation, extract $y$
$$y=-\frac{2 x^2+x+3}{x-3}$$
Plug $y$ in the second equation to get
$$\frac{-2 x^4+5 x^3+49 x^2+51 x+9}{(x-3)^2}=0$$ By inspection $x=-1$ and $x=-3$ are roots of the numerator. So, we are left with
$$\frac{(x+1) (x+3) \left(2 x^2-13 x-3\right)}{(x-3)^2}=0$$ So, the four roots for $x$ and the corresponding $y$'s.